# Elastic serach testing on Production Database (Read only ES usecase)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, testing, pytest

How to test ES data without mocking, which is smart enough to figure out, what should be result at the top

Did google, found most of the libraries are mocking data, but as we have evolving ES indices and logic changes day by day, what should be best practise to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your local elasticsearch to connect production DB when it creates the index.

Comment: Hi @Alexey Zalyotov, thanks for answer, but i am looking some way in which i don't have to hardcode the assert statement, someway which smartly test ES. I don't know if it make much sense from ES point of view, but i don't want to hardcode like we used to have it in python unit test, because data ranking changes based on algorithm, in that way. My test will break every other day